# Aplicar efeito ao mudar value de um input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necessito de uma ajuda com um efeito que queria fazer, mas não estou conseguindo.

Tenho um input do tipo range que vai do `1` ao `10`, sendo o seu valor padrão `5`:

```
<input class="i1" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5">
```

O que quero fazer é que a cada vez que eu mudar o value desse input, o valor do estilo `font-size` do meu elemento `p` seja alterado.

```
<p class="p1">Um texto aleatório</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caso queira trabalhar com jquery o código é esse:

```js
$(document).on('input', '#slider', function() {
 var num = $(this).val();
 console.log(num);
 $(".p1").css({ 'font-size': num*3+'px' });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p1">Um texto aleatório</p>
<input id="slider" class="i1" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5">
```

Comment: Muito obg, era exatamente o que eu estava tentando fazer.

Answer (score 4):

Uma possível solução seria:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log('teste')
  $('input').change(function(){
    $('p').css('font-size', $(this).val()*3)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="i1" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5">
<p class="p1">Um texto aleatório</p>
```

Note que a multiplicação por 3 foi adicionada apenas para melhorar a visualização da mudança.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var min = 10; // Usaremos este como um valor relativo para o efeito.

  var input = document.getElementById('my-range');
  var p     = document.getElementById('my-p-el');

  input.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var size = min + parseInt(this.value);

    p.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  });
}());
```

```html
<input class="i1" id="my-range" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="5" />
<p class="p1" id="my-p-el">Um texto aleatório</p>
```